# Disabling an element when in IE

Tags: javascript, image, html, audio

I'm making an HTML page that plays `<audio>` with a OnClick on an `<img>` tags as a trigger..

**Javascript:**

```
function changeImage()
{
    element=document.getElementById('myimage')
    if (element.src.match("play"))
    {
        element.src="stop.png";
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').src="music.mp3";
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
    } 
    else
    {
        element.src="play.png";
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').src="";
    }
}
```

**IMG tag:**
    `<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()" src="play.png" width="20" height="20" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;">`

**AUDIO tag:**
    `<audio loop id="audiotag1" src="music.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>`

So, here's the problem, since IE8 not support `<audio>` tags, i want to make the image disappear only on IE8 or those who not support `<audio>` tag.  Is it possible? What should I do?
I was once use disabled='disabled' but it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) - namely the condition `<!--[if lte IE 8]>`.

This would hide your image for less than and including IE8 (so IE7, IE6 etc):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
#myimage { 
  display: none; 
}
-->
```

So your whole code for it would look something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]> 
  <style> 
    #myimage { 
      display: none; 
    } 
  </style> 
<![end if]-->
```

Comment: where to put it? i place it right after `<head>` but nothing works

Comment: `<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>
#myimage { 
  display: none; 
}
</style>
<![end if]-->`

Comment: what is "lte" for? when i use one i comment before it works, thanks!

Comment: @HenryJahja lte means less than or equal to - it means IE8 and before, so IE7, IE6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). You can check the support for like anything.

Also Modernizr includes the html5shiv that is a must if you are planning to support oldie with html5.

You can check for

```
if (Modernizr.audio) {}
```

This is **much better** then checking for specific browsers as it checks the actual support for the html5 audio tag and does not make assumptions based on the browser (IE is not the only outdated browser out there :D)

You can also check for actual file format support. The example from the Modernizr [documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5):

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? 'background.ogg' :
            Modernizr.audio.mp3 ? 'background.mp3' :
                                  'background.m4a';
audio.play();
```

(Although this is a confusing way of using nested ? : operators IMHO)

Answer (score -1):

You can try through javascript
check if you detect IE then `return false`

```
if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer") == -1) {
    document.getElementById('myimage').onclick = function () {
         return false;
    }
} else {
    document.getElementById('myimage').onclick = function () {
        alert("cliiing");
        return true;
    }
}
```